# Zend_View prints strange slash ("/") on some pages

Tags: zend-framework, printing, slash

I've got a weird problem. On some pages in my Zend project i can see a strange forward slash coming out of nowhere. It has a random location, sometimes on the begining, sometimes in the end.

The thing is - there is no "/" anywhere in view script, layout or view helper. I've figured out that if I won't use model in the controller then it doesn't show up, but if I do its automaticly printed on my page. And no, there are no "echos" or "prints" in neither controller nor model.

Comment: Do a search in your editor for / in the controller and model, that way you know you definitely didn't miss one.

Comment: It's probably sitting outside the PHP context (`<?php ... ?>`) in one of your files. Do as @Ashley says and perform a file search for `/`

Comment: If you are using chrome (or you have firebug), you can right-click on the / character and "Inspect Element", you may find its whereabouts on the page.

Comment: Voting to close as "Too Localised". Glad you got it sorted though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, problem is solved. I did a file search and found my "/" in front of the whole `<?php ...` in one of my Model file. Each time i used a function from that model i got this slash and now it's gone. I feel kind of like a noob now but as they say, the easier the problem the harder to solve it ;)